Why Does My Website Redirect to HTTP Before HTTPS When Accessed Without a Trailing Slash?
When I enter the URL https://mywebsite.com/journal (without the trailing slash) and check the "Network" tab in the browser console (Inspect Element), the following redirection sequence occurs:
The URL first redirects to http://mywebsite.com/journal (HTTP).
It then redirects again to https://mywebsite.com/journal (HTTPS).
Questions:

Can this be an issue originating from the code?
What specific issues in the code or configuration could be causing this intermediate HTTP redirect?

I'm looking for insights into potential code-level issues or server configuration settings that could be responsible for this behavior. Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
screenshot : https://prnt.sc/_-6beWq5VjCl
: https://d.pr/i/uCeLW5

there's a very high chance this has nothing to do with the WordPress application and is instead a server configuration in HTAccess/Apache/Nginx, have you checked your hosting control panel or spoken to your hosts support?
